# Exclude current post when getting related post on custom post type and taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

The below will return the other post in the same category but it will also return the current post too.

Is there a way to exclude the current post from the query?

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'custom_post_type',
'tax_query'     => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'custom_taxo',
        'field'     => 'term_id',
        'terms'      => array(1,2,5),
        'operator'  => 'IN'
    )
)
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add

```
'post__not_in' => [get_queried_object_id()],
```

to your array of query arguments. `get_queried_object_id()` will return the post ID of the currently viewed single post, and `post__not_in` will skip the posts whos ID's was passed as an array to the parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use `post__not_in` with the `get_the_ID` of the post in this case your code should be like this :

```
                $args = array(
                            'post_type'     => 'custom_post_type',
                            'tax_query'     => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy'  => 'custom_taxo',
                                    'field'     => 'term_id',
                                    'terms'      => array(1,2,5),
                                    'operator'  => 'IN'
                                )
                            ),
                        'post__not_in' => array (get_the_ID()), 

                    );

                $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**Note:** The value has to be an array `'post__not_in' => array (get_the_ID())`